# Insert result of select statement into a SQL Server 2016 table or temp table to then insert or select into

Tags: json, sql-server, bulkinsert, insert-into

Literally the first time I have posted, so please excuse me if I have done it incorrectly.

I'd like to know how I can save the result of this into a SQL Server 2016 table, either a temp or perm table.

Thank you.

```
    DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)

    SET @json = N'{
      "response": [
        {
          "application": {
            "info": {
              "dat_id": "010.2018.00036494.001",
              "development_type": "Residential - Single new dwelling",
              "application_type": "DA",
              "last_modified_date": "2018-12-03T11:35:24+11:00",
              "description": "Residence, Garage & Colorbond Shed, Demolition of Existing Residence & Tree Removal",
              "authority": {
                "ref": "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0",
                "name": "AlburyCity"
              },
              "lodgement_date": "2018-10-26T00:00:00+11:00",
                      )
    […..]


    select * from OPENJSON(@json,'$.response')
    with
    (
    [dat_id] varchar(200) '$.application.info.dat_id',
    [development_type] varchar(200) '$.application.info.development_type',
    [last_modified_date] varchar(200) '$.application.info.last_modified_date',
    [description] varchar(300) '$.application.info.description',
    [ref] varchar(200) '$.application.info.authority.ref',
    [name] varchar(200) '$.application.info.authority.name'
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to save this into a JSON or text column?  Have you already created a table to store your data?

Comment: Hello Tim, I want to put it in as rows and columns, just a normal table that can be queried. After I run the query it is presented just how I would want it to be stored in a table. I have not created the LND table yet, I thought it could be done on the fly, or I can create it. Regards, D.

Comment: That doesn't obviously make any sense, because your JSON content is nested.  You should show us what the output looks like.

Comment: Hi Tim, I just tried to add an image, it said it would put a link in. I cant put in an description of the image.

Comment: See your `select *`? _Before_ that put an `INSERT INTO MyTable (Column1,column2)` and it will insert it into that table

Comment: Thank you, Nick and Bruno, both worked. Can I also select Nick as a correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert into a table from a select result try this way:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)

SET @json = N'{
  "response": [
    {
      "application": {
        "info": {
          "dat_id": "010.2018.00036494.001",
          "development_type": "Residential - Single new dwelling",
          "application_type": "DA",
          "last_modified_date": "2018-12-03T11:35:24+11:00",
          "description": "Residence, Garage & Colorbond Shed, Demolition of Existing Residence & Tree Removal",
          "authority": {
            "ref": "http://gemini:82/ApplicationTracker/atdis/1.0",
            "name": "AlburyCity"
          },
          "lodgement_date": "2018-10-26T00:00:00+11:00",
                  )
[…..]


select * into results_from_query from OPENJSON(@json,'$.response')
with
(
[dat_id] varchar(200) '$.application.info.dat_id',
[development_type] varchar(200) '$.application.info.development_type',
[last_modified_date] varchar(200) '$.application.info.last_modified_date',
[description] varchar(300) '$.application.info.description',
[ref] varchar(200) '$.application.info.authority.ref',
[name] varchar(200) '$.application.info.authority.name'
)
```

The results should be available at : **results_from_query**  table

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp